# How to find the correct values for spring boot mail configuration with docker mail server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to write a spring boot program that will send mail to the recipent.
I am new to this mail things.
I hope docker mail server can help me in this.

here is the docker compose file that docker mail server provides

```
services:
  mailserver:
    image: ghcr.io/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver:latest
    container_name: mailserver
    # Provide the FQDN of your mail server here (Your DNS MX record should point to this value)
    hostname: mail.example.com
    ports:
      - "25:25"
      - "465:465"
      - "587:587"
      - "993:993"
    volumes:
      - ./docker-data/dms/mail-data/:/var/mail/
      - ./docker-data/dms/mail-state/:/var/mail-state/
      - ./docker-data/dms/mail-logs/:/var/log/mail/
      - ./docker-data/dms/config/:/tmp/docker-mailserver/
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - ENABLE_RSPAMD=1
      - ENABLE_CLAMAV=1
      - ENABLE_FAIL2BAN=1
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN # For Fail2Ban to work
    restart: always
```

I want to run this in my local machine as well as my spring boot program
How to add emails and password (sender and recipents ) in this. How to find the recived mail through some mail client like thunder bird. I want to know the configurations. How to manage these users in it.

what should be the value for the spring boot properties.

```
spring.mail.host=
spring.mail.username=
spring.mail.password=
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.port=25
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
```

please give me suggestion on what we need to change in the docker-compose for a smooth functioning